# Turn input submit into asp control

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, submit, aspbutton

I have this:

```
<img src="inc/img/import_up.png" alt="Import" width="73" height="31" style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="src='inc/img/import_ov.png'" onmouseout="src='inc/img/import_up.png'" ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import" CssClass="import_form_submit" OnClientClick="return Import_ClientClick()" onclick="btnImport_Click" />
```

And need to turn it into something like this:

```
                                <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import" CssClass="import_form_submit" OnClientClick="return Import_ClientClick()" onclick="btnImport_Click" />
```

Comment: You can use ImageButton. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use example:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="imagebtn" runat="server"
           AlternateText="Import"
           ImageAlign="left"
           ImageUrl="inc/img/import_up.png"
           OnClick="Import_ClientClick"/>
```